# Can't use you Telegram Bot API functions if the namespace and class of the function in the method parameter

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot

I have this code

```
public static void info()
{
    TGKrybot.SendTextMessageAsync(Telegram.Bot.Args.MessageEventArgs.Message.Chat.Id, "example");
}
```

and this code

```
public static void mybot_OnMessage(object sender, Telegram.Bot.Args.MessageEventArgs msg)
```

In the first code, i cant use `Telegram.Bot.Args.MessageEventArgs.Message.Chat.Id` (and other telegram bot API code ofcourse) even though ive put `using static Telegram.Bot.Args.MessageEventArgs` in the beginning, the problem is is it needs `MessageEventArgs.Message` to be an object, but when i create an object for it it says that theres no `Message` property, method or field in `MessageEventArgs`, ive also tried creating an object for `Telegram.Bot.Args.MessageEventArgs.Message` and that doesnt work because object needs parameters which this doesn't have. And i can't say it in the parameters of the 1st code like i did for the 2nd code because i need the 1st code as a function. How can i fix this, i also don't understand how putting `Telegram.Bot.Args.MessageEventsArgs` in the parameters of my method allows me to use telegram API code.

Answer (score 0):

Your method must has parameters, if you want to do that in `mybot_OnMessage` method, you can use `msg` parameter, but in your case you must let `info` has a `Message` parameter, and pass it in `mybot_OnMessage` to `info` method, so it must be like this:

```
public static void mybot_OnMessage(object sender, Telegram.Bot.Args.MessageEventArgs msg)
{
    info(msg.Message);
}

public static void info(dynamic m)
{
    TGKrybot.SendTextMessageAsync(m.Chat.Id, "example");
}
```

Or you can use it with static class that have `Message` field, but **it's not good**, like this:

```
public static class SharedValues
{
    public static Message Message;
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void mybot_OnMessage(object sender, Telegram.Bot.Args.MessageEventArgs msg)
    {
        SharedValues.Message = msg.Message;
    }
}

public static class AnothorProject
{
    public static void info()
    {
        // Use shared values class
        TGKrybot.SendTextMessageAsync(SharedValues.Message.Chat.Id, "example")
    }
}
```

Comment: If you say `public static void info(Message m)` it gives an error saying Message is not recognized as a method etc, But with `dynamic` it worked

Comment: Ok, I will add it!